# Recursive function designed to ensure that full folder path exists before copying a file to the location

Tags: vba, file-system, ms-access

My recursive function works, but I feel it could be improved... suggestions? The code ensures that a given folder path exists by checking its validity or creating them if they don't already exist, so that afterwards I can, for example copy a file to the location.

```
Function EnsureFolderPath(strP As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EnsureFolderPath_Error

    Dim strParent As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    
    If Len(fso.GetFileName(strP)) > 0 Then
        strP = fso.GetParentFolderName(strP)
    End If
    
    If fso.FolderExists(strP) Then 'folder exist
        EnsureFolderPath = True
        
    ElseIf fso.FolderExists(fso.GetParentFolderName(strP)) Then 'parent folder exist
        fso.CreateFolder strP 'create new subfolder and exit

    Else 'parentfolder doesn't exist, go one level higher
        EnsureFolderPath fso.GetParentFolderName(strP)
        'now that parent folder path has been created
        fso.CreateFolder strP
    End If
    
    If fso.FolderExists(strP) Then EnsureFolderPath = True 'ok and exit

End Function
```

Comment: An alternative to FSO is to use the built-in VBA functions. See the [```CreateFolder```](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools/blob/master/src/LibFileTools.bas#L270) method in my repository. It works on Mac as well and is faster than FSO

Comment: @CristianBuse Thanks! Very good library.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! Just pushed a minor commit if you want the latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If fso.FolderExists(strP) Then 'folder exist
```

This comment isn't needed because it states the obvious. Comments shouldn't be written to tell **what** the code is doing but rather **why** something is done the way it is done.
That beeing said, I would expect a comment here:

```
If Len(fso.GetFileName(strP)) > 0 Then
    strP = fso.GetParentFolderName(strP)
End If
```

stating that the code checks wether the passed `strP` is a filename instead of a foldername.

While we are at this, `strP` isn't a very good name, because at first glance you can't tell what te variable/argument should stay for.

`Dim strParent As String` isn't used and should be removed.

For each entry in the recursive method a `FileSystemObject` is created which isn't ressource-friendly. Either you should have one `FileSystemObject` on class-level, or cretae a second (overloaded) method where you pass a `FileSystemObject` along with the file/foldername.

`If fso.FolderExists(strP) Then EnsureFolderPath = True 'ok and exit`  isn't needed because that is done at the beginning of the method.

```
Function EnsureFolderPath(path As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo EnsureFolderPath_Error

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    If IsFileName(path, fso) Then
        path = fso.GetParentFolderName(path)
    End If   

    EnsureFolderPath = EnsureFolderPathExists(path, fso)

End Function

Function IsFileName(path As String, fso As FileSystemObject) as Boolean
    IsFileName = (fso.GetFileName(path) <> "")
End Function

Function EnsureFolderPathExists(path As String, fso As FileSystemObject) as Boolean

    If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
        EnsureFolderPathExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim parentPath as String
    parentPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(path)

    If EnsureFolderPathExists(parentPath, fso) Then
        fso.CreateFolder path 
        EnsureFolderPathExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    EnsureFolderPathExists = False
        
End Function
```

Be aware **this is not tested** but it should work.

Comment: How would I create an overloaded function in VBA? Is this possible? Or is it as easy as simply adding (Optional fso as FileSystemObject) as a parameter to the function?

Comment: Additionally, since I'm very new to this Stack, how does one show updated work on here... as i've implemented all of your suggestions i could append it to the original question. I suppose we want to keep the original work to show improvements?

Comment: Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. This basically says that after you received an answer you aren't allowed to edit the code in question. Hence after waiting some time (here on Code Review answers can take some time) e.g a day you can ask a follow-up-question with a backlink to the original question.

Comment: Go it! Thanks for the helpful review!

Comment: What is expected for a path like "C:\Test\1\2\3" if only "C:\Test" exists? Should the whole path be created?

Comment: The whole path should be created! I think that part works fairly well. What I'm having trouble with is distinguishing between an actual folder path and one that includes a file

Comment: I have added some code which should do the tasks as well. For method overloadeing in vba I am not quite sure but I think you can use the same method-name as long as the signature (the passed arguments) differ.

Comment: I was able to do it by pasing the fso as I suggested previously. Danke!

Answer (score 1):

```
If Len(fso.GetFileName(strP)) > 0 Then
    strP = fso.GetParentFolderName(strP)
End If
```

The code above removes the last part of the path whether it is a filename of a folder path.  I recommend adding a parameter that identifies whether or not the path has a filename.

Here is how I would do it in pure VBA:

```
Function MkDirEx(PathName As String, hasFileName As Boolean) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Const PathSeparator As String = "/"
    Rem Standardize PathSeparators
    PathName = Replace(PathName, "\", PathSeparator)
    
    Rem Remove Filename from Path
    If hasFileName Then PathName = Left(PathName, InStrRev(PathName, PathSeparator))
    
    Rem n tracks the current directory path that we are validating/creating
    Dim n As Long
    Rem n is initiated to 3 to handle network file locations e.g. //company/
    n = 3
    
    Dim PartialPath As String
    
    Rem Iterate from the base directory to the last folder
    Do
        n = InStr(n, PathName, PathSeparator)
        PartialPath = Left(PathName, n)
        
        If Len(Dir(PartialPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir PartialPath
        n = n + 1
    Loop Until InStr(n, PathName, PathSeparator) = 0
    
    MkDirEx = True

End Function
```